# Casting to int and floating point errors?

Tags: c, casting, floating-point, integer

```
myInt = int( 5 * myRandom() )
```

**myRandom()** is a randomly generated float, which *should* be 0.2.

So this statement **should evaluate to be 1**.

My question: is it possible that **due to a floating point error it will NOT evaluate to 1**?

For example if due to a floating point error something which should be *0.2* could that be *LESS* than that?
IE, for instance consider the following 3 possibilities:

```
int(5 * 0.2 )                = 1 //case 1 normal
int(5 * 0.2000000000000001 ) = 1 //case 2 slightly larger, its OK
int(5 * 0.1999999999999999 ) = 0 //case 3 negative, is NOT OK, as int() floors it
```

Is *case3* even possible?, with *0.1999999999999999* be a result of a floating point error? I have never actually seen a negative epsilon so far, only case 2, when its a slightly bit larger, and thats OK, as when it is cast to int(), that 'floors' it to the correct result. However with a negative epsilon the 'flooring' effect will make the resulting 0.9999999999999996 evaluate to 0.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, no. The multiplication and rounding down should only pay attention to the maximum number of possible significant digits.

Comment: If it's randomly generated, why "should" it be 0.2?

Comment: This is C++, not C. You cannot use the constructor syntax in C.

Comment: Its neither C or C++, its pseudo code. the '0.2' is just an example as well, the actual usage is about Determinism. That is if a Float(nondeterministic) value is cast to an Integer, would that be deterministic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is impossible for myRandom to return .2 because .2 is not representable as a float or a double, assuming your target system is using the IEEE 754 binary floating-point standard, which is overwhelmingly the default.

If myRandom() returns the representable number nearest .2, then myInt will be 1, because the number nearest .2 representable as a float is slightly greater than .2 (it is 0.20000000298023223876953125), and so is the nearest representable double (0.20000000000000001110223024625156540423631668090820312).

In other cases, this will not be true. E.g., the nearest double to .6 is 0.59999999999999997779553950749686919152736663818359375, so myInt will be 2, not 3.

Comment: I like your answer the best, however it is worrying. The real issue was if I could get a deterministic result by casting a float to an int, however from what you have said about the 0.6, it appears not. I will need to do some custom rounding.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, at least as far as the C standard is concerned.

The value `0.2` cannot be represented exactly in a binary floating-point format. The value returned by `myRandom()` will therefore be either slightly below, or slightly above, the mathematical value `0.2`. The C standard permits either result.

Now it may well be that IEEE semantics only permit the result to be slightly greater than `0.2` -- but the C standard doesn't require IEEE semantics. And that's assuming that the result is derived as exactly as possible from the value `0.2`. If the value is generated from a series of floating-point operations, each of which can introduce a small error, it could easily be either less than or greater than `0.2`.

Comment: As an addendum, casting a float to an int rounds down, so if the value is slightly greater than 0.2, you will end up with a product slightly greater than 1, which will round down.

Comment: This just an example, the myRandom() could be anything from 0 to 1, but 0.2 seemed like a good case to illustrate the difference between the outcomes of 0 and 1. The real issue is about Determinism, I was looking to find out if casting a Floatpoint to an int, would that result in a deterministic outcome. It looks like not.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a floating point *error*, it's the way floating point works. Any fraction that isn't 1/(power of 2) can't be exactly represented, and will be rounded either up *or down* to the nearest representable number.

You can fix your code by multiplying by some small epsilon greater than one before converting to integer.

```
myInt = int( 5 * myRandom() * 1.000000000000001 )
```

See [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, depending on the number you choose.
To check a specific number you can always print them with a lot of precision: printf("%1.50f", 0.2)

Answer (score 0):

why not multiply your float by 5.0 and then use the round function to properly round it?

Comment: This is an illustration, these arent the actual figures.